# Any way to avoid Object/casts in the child classes here?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

Following the book "Artificial Intelligence - A Modern Approach" I am trying to make search algorithm implementations (DFS, A*, etc.) that can work with different problems (path from A to B, sliding-block puzzle, etc.) instead of just the one specific problem.

```
public abstract class Problem
{
    protected Problem(object initialState)
    {
        InitialState = initialState;
    }

    public object InitialState { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the state is the goal state
    /// </summary>
    public abstract bool IsGoalState(object state);

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the actions available from the state
    /// </summary>
    public abstract ISet<Action> Actions(object state);

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the state that results after performing the action on the state
    /// </summary>
    public abstract object ResultState(object state, Action action);

    /// <summary>
    ///  Returns the cost of action to reach from state to reachedState
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="state">The state from which the action will be performed</param>
    /// <param name="action">One of the actions available in the state</param>
    /// <param name="reachedState">The state that results after performing the action</param>
    public virtual int StepCost(object state, Action action, object reachedState)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

_

```
public class Node
{
    public Node(object state)
    {
        State = state;
        PathCost = 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">The action that was applied to the parent to generate the node</param>
    /// <param name="stepCost">The cost from the parent node to this node</param>
    public Node(object state, Node parent, Action action, int stepCost)
        : this(state)
    {
        Parent = parent;
        Action = action;
        if (Parent != null)
            PathCost = Parent.PathCost + stepCost;
    }

    public object State { get; }

    public Node Parent { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The action that was applied to the parent to generate the node
    /// </summary>
    public Action Action { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The cost of the path from the initial statee to the node
    /// </summary>
    public int PathCost { get; }

    public bool IsRootNode => Parent == null;

    public IEnumerable<Node> PathFromRoot()
    {
        var path = new Stack<Node>();

        var node = this;
        while (!node.IsRootNode)
        {
            path.Push(node);
            node = node.Parent;
        }
        path.Push(node); // root

        return path;
    }
}
```

_

```
public abstract class Action
{
    /// <summary>
    /// true if it is a "No Operation" action
    /// </summary>
    public virtual bool IsNoOp()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public string Name => GetType().Name;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

public class NoOp : Action
{
    public override bool IsNoOp()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public abstract class EightPuzzleAction : Action
{
}

/// <summary>
/// Move the blank tile to the left
/// </summary>
public class MoveLeft : EightPuzzleAction
{
}
// the same MoveRight, MoveTop, MoveBottom
```

In order to do that I can implement methods from this base `Problem` class and pass that concrete instance to a search algorithm (that accepts `Problem`).

```
class EightPuzzleProblem : Problem
{
    private readonly int[,] _goalState =
    {
        {0, 1, 2},
        {3, 4, 5},
        {6, 7, 8},
    };

    public EightPuzzleProblem(int[,] initialState) : base(initialState)
    { }

    public override bool IsGoalState(object state)
    {
        var puzzleState = (int[,]) state;

        ......... <check if puzzleState is the same as _goalState>
    }
    ............
}

class DepthFirstSearch
{
    public IEnumerable<Action> Search(Problem p)
    {
        return DfsRecursive(p, new Node(p.InitialState));
    }

    public IEnumerable<Action> DfsRecursive(Problem p, Node node)
    {
        if (p.IsGoalState(node.State))
            return node.PathFromRoot();

        .......<simple DFS implementation>
    }
}

// usage example

var dfs = new DepthFirstSearch();
var result = dfs.Search(new EightPuzzleProblem(initialState));

if (!result.Any)
   // fail
if (result.Count == 1 && result[0].IsNoOp)
   // already at goal


foreach (var act in result)
{
    if (act is MoveLeft) .....
}
```

But I see one inconvenience with my class design: in the concrete class implementation code I need to have a lot of casts from `object`. Is there any way to avoid that? 
If I make the `Problem` class generic and inherit `ConcreteProblem` from `Problem<Something>` then I will not be able to use it via `Problem`...

Comment: The problem is the method `IsGoalState` in `Problem`. Does it really need an `object` instead of something more specific? Furthermore can you limit your code as much as possible to only those classes that show your actual problem? I doubt we need `Node`, `DepthFirstSearch` and `Action` for this question, do we?

Comment: What do you mean about more specific? Something like `IState`/`State`? Maybe, but it would still have the same issue with casts from `IState` to `MyProblemState` since the base class has no idea what data will be needed for representation of the concrete problem state.

Answer (score 1):

You could actually make `Problem` generic with the generic param set to the actual state.

```
public abstract class Problem<T> where T : IState{ 
    public abstract bool IsGoalState(T state);
}
```

Within your derived classes you can now simply derive from `Problem` passing the actual type of `IState` as generic parameter:

```
class MyDerived : Problem<MyState> {
    public override bool IsGoalState(MyState state) { ... }
}
```

Comment: But as I understand then I will not be able to use it in the `DepthFirstSearch` method which accepts `Problem`.

Comment: For this you can simply introduce both a generic `Problem`-class which inherits a non-generic one that you can use on the outside.

Comment: You mean something like this? https://gist.github.com/AlexP11223/2f7e538202bb8b0d94906ec8e782227a     `public abstract class ProblemGeneric<T> : Problem
    {
        public override bool IsGoalState(object state)
        {
            return IsGoalStateGeneric((T) state);
        }

        public abstract bool IsGoalStateGeneric(T state);
    }`

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about something like this before asking the question, but creating generic wrapper for each method/property doesn't seem like a clean and smell-less idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you inject your GoalState too and make GameState also pluggable using the interface like below. In this way you can implement any operation you want to do on two States in the concrete class and Problem class just needs to call those functions. Also you can have different types of states too.

```
public abstract class Problem<T> where T:IGameState
{
    protected Problem(T initialState)
    {
        InitialState = initialState;
    }

    public T InitialState { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the state is the goal state
    /// </summary>
    public abstract bool IsGoalState(T state);


}

public class EightPuzzleProblem<T> : Problem<T> where T : IGameState
{
    private readonly T _goalState;

    public EightPuzzleProblem(T initialState, T goalState)
        : base(initialState)
    {
        _goalState = goalState;
    }
    public override bool IsGoalState(T state)
    {
        return _goalState.IsEqual(state);
    }
}

public interface IGameState
{
    bool IsEqual(IGameState state);
}

public class EightPuzzleGameState : IGameState
{
    private readonly int[,] _goalState =
    {
        {0, 1, 2},
        {3, 4, 5},
        {6, 7, 8},
    };

    public bool IsEqual(IGameState state)
    {
        //Compare state with _goalState
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I am trying to do something similar + move methods for retrieving next states to `IState` instead of `Problem`.